# Beamer onslide delayed and missing notes

Tags: beamer, notes

I am having troubles with the use of `\onslide<+->` and beamer notes.

For the following snippet

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
    \onslide<+->
    1111
    \onslide<+->
    2222
    \onslide<+->
    333
\end{frame}

\note[itemize]
{
    \item{First note.}
    \item<2->{Second note.}
}

\end{document}
```

I obtain the following result

[image]

While I actually want to see "first note" appearing with "1111" and "second note" with "2222". Interestingly, the "second note" does not appear at all.
What am I doing wrong?